# Sorting barh plots in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting, plot

I have data plotted in barh plot:

[image]

now I would like to sort in ascending or descending way, can somebody help me how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Marko

Comment: How exactly are you plotting your data? Can't you sort it before creating the plot?

Comment: please post the code you are using to create the `barh` plot so we can provide better answers.

Answer (score 4):

In Matlab, sorting (and all data manipulation) is handled before a figure is generated. Once it has been rendered the most you can do is change its appearance.

I don't know the specifics of your (bioinformatics?) dataset, but my guess based on the image you provided is that you have some vector `data`, and then a cell array containing strings, `labels`.

To get your bar plot we need to:

1. sort the data vector
2. rearrange the cell array to reflect the new sequence
3. `barh()`
4. (optional) change the *sort order* of the barh plot

It's important to keep track of default sort orders in Matlab:

- `barh` plots vectors according to their **indices** in **descending** order (i.e. elements with higher indices appear first)
- `sort` sorts vectors according to their **values** in **ascending** order

Here is a simplified example:

```
data = [35.42, 32.9, 36.8];
labels = { 'FOO_fastqc', 'BAR_fastqc', 'BAZ_fastqc'};

% Sort the Data & Rearrange Labels
[sorted_data, new_indices] = sort(data); % sorts in *ascending* order
sorted_labels = labels(new_indices); 

% Plot in Descending Order
figure();
barh(sorted_data);
set(gca,'YTickLabel',sorted_labels);

% Plot in Ascending Order
figure();
barh(sorted_data);
set(gca,'YTickLabel',sorted_labels);
set(gca,'YDir','reverse'); % Flips the Y Axis
```

[image]

Comment: For those having A LOT of labels to show... and you want to show them all, don't you? This does the trick: set(gca,'YTick',1:numel(sorted_labels),'YTickLabel',sorted_labels)